# Does mod_rewrite only translate external requests to internal files and not vice versa?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I think this is a very stupid question so I apologise, as i think i may completely misunderstand mod_rewrite.

Say you have a URL

```
www.domain.com/products/item.php?id=1234
```

mod_rewrite can rewrite that to a friendly URL

```
wwww.domain.com/products/item/1234
```

(for example)

So, if i type in wwww.domain.com/products/item/1234 this will be rewritten to www.domain.com/products/item.php?id=1234 and that page is served. Fine.

But what if you type in www.domain.com/products/item.php?id=1234 - that page will be served but not rewritten to the friendly URL.

So my question is can you rewrite internal file names automatically? For example, all URLs on my site are currently in the www.domain.com/products/item.php?id=1234 format. When a user clicks this link can this be rewritten to the friendly URL? Or should you always hard code in the friendly URL?

Im sorry if that made little sense! Im getting confused because i want to rewrite non-friendly to friendly URL, but then serve the non friendly URL - so wont that cause an infinite redirect loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mod_rewrite can't really internally rewrite URLs across domains, though it *could* proxy them (using `P` option in RewriteRule). Assuming that the domain is the same, you could do something to redirect the client's browser to a friendly URL if the old one is used while internally rewriting the friendly URL back to the old one, but they have to be both the same domain. You do this by looking at the actual request (`%{THE_REQUEST}`) variable instead of looking at the URI, which changes as they get rewritten internally.

This redirects the browser when the old URLs are used to the friendly URLs

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^([A-Z]{3,9})\ /products/item\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^products/item\.php$ /products/item/%1? [R=301,L]
```

This rewrites internally when a friendly URL is used:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^([A-Z]{3,9})\ /products/item/[0-9]+
RewriteRule ^products/item/([0-9]+) /products/item.php?id=$1  [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Mod_rewrite does not automatically rewrite the "none friendly" urls to the friendly urls. You have to add some rules yourself to do this.

Also Mod_rewrite does not modify the links inside your html, css, or whatever you use. You need to change those yourself.

If a user uses the friendly url, it will never know that it is rewritten. Mod_rewrite is tranparent from the user's point of view. You can add a `[R]` flag to your rules which makes apache send a redirect to the client. This way the client does see the rewritten url.

Redirecting the unfriendly to the fiendly url, should only be done to help search engines (and to prevent link-rot, but that's more rare). This can be done without a redirect loop, unlike Sergey says.

Try looking around here on SO to find a script that does the redirect from the unfriendly to the fiendly url. Let me know if you can't find it, and I'll help.